# Return XML formatted data directly to the browser using Jersey

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey

I'm doing a `@GET` request using Jersey and want to return XML formatted data directly to the browser. My method is annotated as the following:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
```

Here is the line that should be displaying the data:

```
response.getWriter().println(Docs.get(i));
```

I'm not sure how to get the data to display correctly. I'm guessing calling `getWriter().println()` on an XML document is not correct but I'm not sure what the right way to do it is. Currently I'm getting the error

```
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
```

when I run my code but the data returned is not empty as I have tested it with other formats.